# How to export screen verbose result from Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to disable computer account, and then export success/failure result to a file. but I tried export-csv, out-file, and other ways. all had a empty file as result. any clues?

Thanks!

```
$MyDN= (Get-ADComputer testmachine).DistinguishedName
Disable-ADAccount -Identity $MyDN -Verbose |Out-File c:\result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from [about_Redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx):

```
  Operator  Description                Example  
  --------  ----------------------     ------------------------------
  4>        Sends verbose output to    Import-Module * -Verbose 4> Verbose.txt
            the specified file.

  4>>       Appends verbose output     Import-Module * -Verbose 4>> Save-Verbose.txt
            to the contents of the 
            specified file.

  4>&1      Sends verbose output (4)   Import-Module * -Verbose 4>&1
            and success output (1)    
            to the success output
            stream.
```

**Edit:** You may want to consider using the -PassThrough argument, or if neither of those options gives you what you are looking for maybe a Try/Catch can provide it.

Comment: second the edit. Disable-Account doesnt really have output. Just errors is something is wrong. It wont even tell you if the account is already is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the account is actually disabled and write that result to the file:

```
$MyDN= (Get-ADComputer testmachine).DistinguishedName
Disable-ADAccount -Identity $MyDN

$comp = Get-ADComputer -Identity $MyDN -Properties Enabled
"{0} disabled: {1}" -f $comp.Name, (!$comp.Enabled) | Out-File 'C:\result.txt'
```

`-f` is PowerShell's format operator. It takes an array of strings (or objects that can be converted to strings) and replaces placeholders in a format string with them (basically like Python's `%` operator).

```
<format string with placeholders> -f <string>, <string>, ...
```

The placeholders are zero-based numbers in curly brackets (`{0}`, `{1}`, ...) with each number referring to an index of the array with the replacement strings. That way you can insert the same string at multiple positions in the format string:

```
PS C:\> "{0}: {1}" -f 'foo', 'bar'
foo: bar
PS C:\> "{0}: {1}-{0}" -f 'foo', 'bar'
foo: bar-foo
```

The format string also allows you to format the arguments in specific ways by adding modifiers to the placeholders, e.g. for printing numbers as hexadecimal numbers, currency or percent values:

```
PS C:\> "0x{0:X}" -f 255
0xFF
PS C:\> "{0:p}" -f 0.23
23.00 %
PS C:\> "{0:c}" -f 42
$ 42.00
```

formatting decimals:

```
PS C:\> "{0:n4}" -f (1/7)
0.1429
```

or aligning output:

```
PS C:\> "{0,10:n2}`n{1,10:n2}`n{2,10:n2}" -f 13.5, 1402, 5.1491
     13.50
  1,402.00
      5.15
```

See [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) for further information on formatting strings with this operator.

Comment: sorry I am still a beginner, can you ignite me the format usage of this sentence? "{0} disabled: {1}" -f $comp.Name, (!$comp.Enabled)

Answer (score 0):

While there is verbose output from `Disable-Account` it does not provide the answers you are looking for. A simple try/catch block might address this for you

```
$accounts = "jpilot","notexist"
$results = @()

ForEach($account in $accounts){
    try{
        Disable-ADAccount $user -ErrorAction Stop
        $results += "$user was disabled"
    } catch {
        $results += "Unable to disable $($user):  $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

$results | Out-File c:\result.txt -Encoding Ascii
```

Basically try and disable the accounts building a result array as you go. If there was no error you can assume that it is disabled. If you *really* wanted to be sure you could check it again with `Get-Aduser` or `Get-AdComputer` but that seems redundant. `-ErrorAction Stop` will cause any failure to be caught by the `catch`. If that is the case output the reason for the failure so that it can be checked later.